# Find the minimum value of the maximum eigenvalue of operator A?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

So we are given the following:

- Operator $A$ with $Au=-u''$;
- $u \in D_A = \{u\colon[a,b]\rightarrow R,u\in C^2([a,b]),u(a)=u(b)=0\}$;
- $D_A$ is dense in $L^2((a,b))$.

Find the minimum value that is possible for the maximum eigenvalue of $A$.

So I have proven that:

- operator $A$ is self-adjoint
- Operator $A$ is positively defined that is $\langle Ax ,x\rangle >0$.
  But afterwards I'm really not sure how to handle the problem.

Comment: Isn't $\sqrt{\lambda}=\frac{k\pi}{b-a}$ an eigenvalue for $k=0,1,2,...$? In this case there would be no maximum eigenvalue.

Comment: Ok I found the same eigenvalues as you did. I thought due to the "operator" concept things were handled differently. So probably the minimum value would for k=0

Comment: Actually, $k=0$ is not an eigenvalue (by the boundary conditions), so the minimum eigenvalue would be for $k=1$.